# Trying to make Login form by using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Guys I'm trying to make a Log in form by using Ajax and PHP. Every-time when I submit the form I'm getting the right response, but the problem here is that I have an "IF CONDITION" in my Javascript file did not execute while I get a "success" response. I don't know why. This is my code, please anybody help.

**Ajax File**

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
    return true;
    }
}
```

**Javascript File handling Log in** - The problem is here in this file

```
function signin(){
    var logstat = _("logstat");
    var loge = _("SignInEmail").value;
    var logp = _("SignInPasswordActive").value;
    if(loge == "" || loge == "Email address" || logp == ""){
    logstat.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data.";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        logstat.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ax = ajaxObj("POST", "signin.php");
        ax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ax) == true) {
                if(ax.responseText != "success"){
                    logstat.innerHTML = ax.responseText;
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";              
                } else {
                    //Here is the problem I get success in Ajax Response, but this condition did not run
                    logstat.innerHTML = "login success";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
        ax.send("le="+loge+"&lp="+logp);
    }   
}
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['le']) && isset($_POST['lp'])){
        $p = $_POST['lp'];
        require_once('includes/database.php');
        include_once('randStrGen.php');
        $e = $_POST['le'];              
        $p_hash = md5($p);      
        $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
        if($e == "" || $e == "Email address" || $p == ""){
            echo "Fill out all of the form data.";
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db->connection, $sql);
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
            if($numrows == 0){
                echo "This account is not exist";
                exit();
            }else{
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $db_id = $row['id'];
                $db_em = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $row['email']);
                $db_ps = substr($row['password'],10,-10);   
                if($p_hash != $db_ps){
                    echo "Email or Password combination failed";
                    exit();
                }else{
                    //This is the successful Log in condition
                    echo "success";
                    exit();
                }
            }
            exit();
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you alert `ax.responseText` and verify that the value is indeed 'success'? Maybe there's a space behind or in front of it.

Comment: +1, was just about to say that..

Comment: Btw, why do you call `exit()` all the time in PHP?

Comment: Also you can leave out the `== true` inside the if statement when comparing to an actuall boolean.

Comment: @GolezTrol When I was alert ax.responseText I got 'success' and there are no spaces behind or in-front of it. Also I removed the useless exit() but it didn't work

Comment: @derylius I removed ==true so the condition become if(ajaxReturn(ax)) instead of if(ajaxReturn(ax) == true) but it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't say it's gonna solve the problem, just that it's useless.
Btw did you try swaping the condition so checking if it's equals (even ===) to 'success' and do the rest in the else clause?

Comment: @derylius Finally it was resolved, I just swapping the condition as you told me, and YESSSSSSSS it worked perfectly. I changed the condition to become if(ax.responseText = "success") instead of if(ax.responseText != "success"). Thanks man for your help.

Comment: Thanks for everybody tried to help me resolve this problem.

Comment: @derylius I need to know how can I mark your comment as the answer of my question, or how can I vote for your answer, or Actually how can I explain my pleasure for your help, because I'm a new user in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I add it as an answer so you should be able to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swaping the condition so checking if it's equals (even ===) to 'success' and do the rest in the else clause